# How to abort winsock blocking call?

Tags: c++, winsock, blocking

I use Winsock 2 in C++, and wonder how to make my server stop reading from the client connection. The reading thread gets blocked in `recv()` and I have no idea how to abort it. One way to do this is use non-blocking sockets with `select()`, but this thread has to wait before checking the new `select()`.

What is the proper way to stop reading the socket?

Comment: Shutdown the socket for read. That will cause the receive to unblock and return zero, and it should already be programmed to close the socket and stop reading and exit the thread when that happens.

Answer (score 2):

To abort the blocking call to `recv()`, you can close the socket with `closesocket()` from *another* thread. Even if it's a bit ugly, it should work.

You can try to `shutdown()` the socket too (I never tested that).

Comment: Do you know that the `recv` is even started when calling `closesocket`? What if it isn't?

Comment: @curiousguy: I agree with your concerns. According to the ["Remarks" section of the Microsoft documentation on the closesocket() function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock/nf-winsock-closesocket#remarks), the socket descriptor could immediately be reused after closesocket is called. Therefore, this could introduce a [race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition). According to the Microsoft documentation, closesocket() should therefore never be called concurrently with another Winsock function call on the same socket.

Comment: This is literally impossible to do. As curiousguy points out, there's no way you can ensure the `closesocket` comes after the call to `recv` and if the calls execute in the other order, results can be entirely unpredictable. I would downvote this answer three times if I could.

Comment: It seems it's possible to avoid a racing condition by doing something like this: 1) set a termination flag for the 'recv' thread. 2) set the socket handle to INVALID_SOCKET so the thread about to go into 'recv' would not use a handle we are about to close/have closed. 3) sleep for 100~ ms. 4) Issue the 'closesocket'. The thread coming out of 'recv' can detect termination upon exiting the call, and if it's about to go into 'recv' then it would attempt to do it with INVALID_SOCKET - no harm, no foul. The 100ms should be enough to avoid the racing condition. Any comments?

Comment: But it is still hacky; I don't like the idea of sweeping the rug from under the `recv` function's feet by closing a socket it's waiting on (or perhaps in the middle of other stuff before/after its wait). And if there's any explicit documentation that states that this sort of thing should not be done, then I would be even happier to not do this. There should be another safer and less hacky alternative (I am trying them out at the moment).

Comment: Never mind. As pointed out, in the remarks section for `closesocket`: "_A Winsock client must never issue closesocket on s concurrently with another Winsock function call._"

Answer (score 1):

If your program has other things to do besides working with socket I/O, you should not block in the first place.

You claim your thread *must* wait, but that's just a reflection of your program's current design.  You should redesign it so it works with some form of non-blocking sockets.  Every networking problem can be addressed using non-blocking sockets.

Since you're using Winsock, you have [many alternatives](http://tangentsoft.net/wskfaq/articles/io-strategies.html) here, not just `select()`.  `select()` is a good choice only if your application must run on many platforms and you are unable to use the superior (but mutually incompatible) alternatives available on every modern platform.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to use `select`, `accept` and `recv` without polling or timeout intervals.

Whether you want a server or just a client (or many clients), this solution will work all the same. This answer assumes you will have a dedicated thread for calling `accept`, and a thread per each client that connects in.

1. Create a socketpair (on Windows, you would need to create a localhost server and connect a client to it, then close the listening socket). Call the two sockets SocketPairSend and SocketPairReceive.
2. For your TCP server, the `accept` thread would call `select`, passing 2 sockets into the `readfds` parameter: the listening socket and SocketPairReceive.
3. For TCP clients, you would also call `select`, passing 2 sockets into the `readfds` parameter: the client socket and SocketPairReceive.

In my test code, I have the `accept` thread, threads for new clients received from `accept`, and additional clients connected to the server via `connect`, all using the `select` call, passing the same extra SocketPairReceive socket.

When you want to shut the server down, simply send a byte on SocketPairSend, and all the threads would wake up from their `select` calls.

You could avoid using a socketpair if you already have a server. You can just connect a dummy client in and use its socket (that you got from `accept`) for your `accept` and client threads to pass into `select`. But I prefer the socketpair approach because it works for all scenarios (i.e., when you don't have a TCP server). Socketpair underpins the concept better - it acts as an event that you can wait on, one that `select` can accept (Linux is more flexible in this regard, but on Windows, `select` can only accept sockets).

A word on other suggestions that I've come across:

- Using `closesocket` appears to work but it's explicitly stated in its documentation to not do this while another blocking call is in progress. It also seems hacky. There's also a racing condition to be aware of.
- Using `shutdown` only works in some scenarios. It never works for aborting `accept`. It's also a little dodgy for the same reasons `closesocket` is. Sweeping the rug from under the socket system's feet may potentially create weird results.
- You may abort an `accept` by connecting a client in - simple and harmless, but a little hacky. I needed a solution that worked for `recv` as well, so I ultimately ditched this.
- On Windows, you can use `WSARecv` and `WaitForMultipleObjects`. I've not tried it. I saw it on this old Google Groups post [here](https://groups.google.com/g/microsoft.public.win32.programmer.networks/c/qLFezDFTiiQ).

Before everyone jumps to say that I should not be using blocking sockets etc, well I wanted a simple solution, for a simple project I am working on and felt compelled to write an answer that worked for me, using the good old `select`, `accept` and `recv` with blocking sockets and threads. Hope this helps!

Comment: "It's also a little dodgy for the same reasons` closesocket` is": no it isn't. It doesn't close the socket FD, so there is no possibility of it being reallocated, so no race.

Comment: I had a doubt when writing that. What I had in mind was not that the socket would be closed by shutdown but that issuing a shutdown on a socket being in recv is something that doesn't seem very kosher. Imagine if you wrote a library, would you want a concurrent call like that being issued? I can't vouch for the innards of the chain of all the winsock dlls and how each one might get tripped up by working on a socket that's been shutdown. A thread might be in the process of calling recv and could in be anywhere within that DLL chain's code. It just doesn't seem right...

Comment: The words "sweeping the rug from winsock's feet" best describe what I am trying to get at. You're right that there's no race, I knew that. But it's irrelevant - shutdown doesn't work to abort a recv or select (I wonder if select with writefds or exceptfds may be aborted? hmm) try it yourself and see. In summary, closesocket during recv is an undocumented hack that is explicitly documented against and using shutdown (though doesn't have the same documentation against issuing it during another winsock call) isn't far from that.

Comment: Err. edit comment timeout got me. Correction: "I can't vouch for the innards of the chain of all the winsock dlls and how each one might get tripped up by working on a socket that's been/BEING shutdown."