# Unblock a Blocked Winsock accept() Call

Tags: winsock

I am using Winsock under VS 2008.

I have a thread dedicated to accepting incoming TCP connection requests via a blocking call to accept(). When the time comes for my app to shut down, I need to somehow unblock this thread so it can perform its shutdown work and exit. Is there a way I may unblock accept()?

I will post another question in case there is no way to unblock accept(). That question is: If I perform a hard kill of the thread that is blocked on accept(), will anything bad happen (corruption of OS data structures, etc.)?

Thanks,
Dave

Comment: Can't you close the socket you are blocked on? This will cause `accept()` to return.

Comment: IME, just exiting the app while the accept() is blocked is just fine.  The OS will clean up and nothing will get broken.  If you really, absolutely have to explicitly clean up, then close the socket from another thread, as suggested by other posters.

Comment: I've answered it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77428975/1271778)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One way to unblock a blocking `accept()` is to close the listening socket from another thread.  Otherwise, you can put the listening socket into non-blocking mode and use `select()` (which does support a timeout) to detect when `accept()` can be called without blocking.

Comment: I believe that this solution is prone to a race. There is window where one thread is in a loop but out of `select()`, checking `select()`'s return value; second thread successfully does `closesocket()`; third thread opens a new socket with the same handle value; first thread resumes waiting in the `select()` but now for a different socket with the same handle value.

Comment: If you use the `select()` approach I mentioned, then the second thread doesn't need to call `closesocket()`. It can simply set a signal that the first thread looks for so it can close its own socket at its earliest convenience. The use of `select()` ensures that the first thread is not blocked indefinately in `accept()`, by simply not calling `accept()` until `select()` says to.

Answer (score 2):

Straight forward and specific for Windows, closesocket() returns without error and unblocks a thread calling accept().

Polling on select() is not really what you want!
Connecting from an additional thread is not really what you want!

E.g. for linux, close(socket) does not unblock a listening thread,
but shutdown(socket, SHUT_RD) will; in addition the socket needs to be closed.

Comment: Thanks so much, shutdown(socket, SHUT_RD) is the only thing that works. unfortunately 
 the correct respone has no votes :(

Comment: The question actually refers to windows. Where always, when you create a platform abstraction including sockets, you pass equivalent question. And I was wondering, too, that you find the answer only nested in very selected threads.

Answer (score 1):

A robust way to unblock the accept() call from another thread is to create a connection by using connect(). Of course, the thread needs to know what IP address and port is being listened.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>One approach I've used in the past is to supply a timeout value for accept() - and when it timesout, you check a "cancel" flag - if set, you stop - if not, you go back into the loop with the accept() call.</strike>

I think killing the thread would work, but you should be careful to ensure it's your thread and, for example, not a .NET threadpool thread.

**EDIT:** Remy's right, and to think I even did a quick google to verify the struct I recall exists - too quick, it seems.  Blush/etc.

If you want to maintain the blocking semantics, it would see closing the socket from another thread (or Aborting your blocking thread) would be the way to go.

Comment: `accept()` in WinSock does not have a timeout parameter of its own.  You have to put the listening socket into non-blocking mode and then use `select()` (which does support a timeout) to detect when `accept()` can be called without blocking.

Comment: killing the thread is much more complete,that would involve too much other stuff need to consider.