# in winsock, how would i stop a accept function from blocking from another thread?

Tags: winapi, winsock

so here's my situation. I'm working with winsock, learning some things about networking and protocol devlopment, and i've reached an impasse. I'm right now doing a server that blocks at an accept call, but has another thread in the background waiting for user input and handling user input. this user input is used for commands like send,ping, and say, etc. but now i would like a command called exit that will shut down winsock, release all open connections, and then end the program. problem is, this accept thread is still blocking.

so here's the questions. 1) is there anyway to stop a winsock function from blocking while it's called, and 2) is something like this in non-blocking mode:

```
while(m_continue)
{
      Sleep(1);
      tempsock = accept(m_listenSock, NULL, NULL);
      if(tempsock != INVALID_SOCKET)
      {
            if(WSAGetLastError() == WSAEWOULDBLOCK)
                  continue;
            else 
                  return 1;
      }
      break;
{
```

superfluous or just too inneficient to use?

Comment: I've answered it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77428975/1271778)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the user command thread, when you handle the "exit" command, close the `m_listenSock` socket. The blocking `accept()` call will immediately drop out with `INVALID_SOCKET`.

Be sure not to close the `m_listenSock` handle twice.

Comment: This does not work for me on Windows 7. Both the closesocket() and accept() calling threads get blocked.

Comment: try this:
Note  When issuing a blocking Winsock call such as accept, Winsock may need to wait for a network event before the call can complete. Winsock performs an alertable wait in this situation, which can be interrupted by an asynchronous procedure call (APC) scheduled on the same thread. Issuing another blocking Winsock call inside an APC that interrupted an ongoing blocking Winsock call on the same thread will lead to undefined behavior, and must never be attempted by Winsock clients.