# Interrupt a receiving socket

Tags: c++, sockets, timeout, winsock

I have a WinSock `mySocket` that receives in a loop like so:

```
while(keepGoing){
    FD_SET fsd;
    FD_ZERO(&fds);
    FD_SET(mySocket, &fds);

    int result = select(1+mySocket, &fds, (fd_set *)0, (fd_set *)0, &timeout);
    if(result>0 && FD_ISSET(mySocket, &fds){
        result = recvfrom(mySocket, buff, NUM_BYTES, (struct sockaddr *)&add, &length);
        // do stuff       
    }
}
```

If I want to stop receiving I can set `keepGoing` to false, but the socket may still be waiting for `timeout` before it sees that `keepGoing` has changed.

Assuming that we do not want to change the value of the timeout, is there a reliable way to tell the socket to stop receiving without waiting for the timeout to occur?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can raise a benign signal and check the `keepGoing` flag when the `errno` is `EINTR`. Or, you can create a `pipe` and add the read end to your `select` set. Close the write end after setting the `keepGoing` flag.

```
int quitfds[2];
pipe(quitfds);

    //...
    FD_SET(quitfds[0], &fds);
    //...

    if (FD_ISSET(quitfds[0], &fds)) {
        close(quitfds[0]);
        continue;
    }
```

**Edit:** Adam points out that I missed the `Winsock` reference in the question. You can use a `socketpair` instead of a `pipe`. It doesn't seem to be implemented on Windows, but I found [a workaround here](https://github.com/zpao/spidernode/blob/master/src/platform_win32_winsock.cc). Ben points out that `WSAEventSelect` allows mixing of different event objects. Thanks to both.

Comment: That's great for Unix, but Windows doesn't have signals, and WinSock's `select` implementation can only deal with socket objects, not other type of file-like objects such as pipes.

Comment: @Adam: True of `select`, but Windows also has `WSAEventSelect` which does enable mixing.

Comment: @Adam: Thanks for pointing that out to me, I missed that in the question.

Comment: @Ben: Oh good point, I did not not know about `WSAEventSelect`.

Comment: If it's TCP and you've completely finished with the socket, shut it down for input. That will deliver an end-of-stream to the `recv()` method (return value of zero). You can still write to the socket.

Comment: I've answered it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77428975/1271778)