# C - Detecting TCP socket broken connection

Tags: c++, c, sockets, network-programming

I am implementing a tcp server socket. The server communicates with a client socket in another device. 
 
The problem is: if the connection suddenly broken (cable removed), the recv() function didn't return. 
I cannot implement ping pong (heartbeat) mechanism because I don't control the device implementation. 
After searching on internet for a while, I found this tutorial: http://tldp.org/HOWTO/TCP-Keepalive-HOWTO/overview.html 
But I don't fully understand the tutor. If I call setsockopt() on SO_KEEPALIVE, TCP_KEEPCNT, TCP_KEEPIDLE, TCP_KEEPINTVL, the tutor says it will override system-wide variables (tcp_keepalive_time, tcp_keepalive_intvl, tcp_keepalive_probes) 
Does it affect other sockets created by another thread/process?

Comment: `setsockopt()` affects only the socket you give it. So no, setting keep-alive values on one socket will have no affect on other sockets, or the system as a whole

Comment: Set the timeout for revc(), check documentation

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2131525/cwinsock2-0how-to-abort-winsock-blocking-call

Comment: @Mannoj Your link has no relevance whatsoever. If you think otherwise please explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TCP keep-alive functionality does allow you to detect broken connections. You need to enable it explicitly for your socket and change the defaults so that it detects a broken connection earlier, like your tutor instructed you.

> But I don't fully understand the tutor. If I call `setsockopt()` on `SO_KEEPALIVE`, `TCP_KEEPCNT`, `TCP_KEEPIDLE`, `TCP_KEEPINTVL`, the tutor says it will override system-wide variables (tcp_keepalive_time, tcp_keepalive_intvl, tcp_keepalive_probes)
>   Does it affect other sockets created by another thread/process?

It doesn't, `setsockopt` only affects the socket you pass as the argument to it.

Comment: Just a note: What I found out recently is that some firewalls cut the connection although tcp keep-alive is set and below firewall rules, so it may not be a complete solution...

Comment: @MarioTheSpoon TCP keep-alives still detect a broken connection. You are talking about a different problem of keeping a connection open by a router.

Comment: True, just wanted to ppoint this out since it ruined the day for one of my customers (who implemented reconnection handly wrongly bc 'it could never happen') :-)

Comment: @MarioTheSpoon That wouldn't be the 1st time misconfigured or non-compliant network hardware ruined someone's day. And this is why people implement application-level heartbeats - to work-around such hardware.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin I marked your answer as accepted. But one more question: before, if I use recv() alone, when connection broken, recv() did not return. But when I setsockopt() with SO_KEEPALIVE, the recv() return when timeout expired. Does recv() do something with SO_KEEPALIVE?

Comment: @Joker TCP keep-alives carry 0 bytes of data and your application can observe keep-alives only through errors it generates, such as `recv` or `send` returning an error.

Comment: @Joker You really shouldn't use TCP keepalives for this. They're designed to be a system-level workaround for applications that predate TCP and can't be modified to support something sensible. You are writing an application designed to work with TCP.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I don't think your warning has enough supporting information to take it seriously.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin There's not really enough room in a comment to give a full explanation and it's not really necessary to answer the question. A receive timeout will work in his case since the other end is doing application-level keep alives. Hopefully, I provided enough information that someone who wanted to know more could find more information without too much effort.

Answer (score 0):

TCP provides no good way to detect a broken connection on a side that is not sending. If the protocol the device uses does not provide any way for the server to detect a broken connection, the protocol is broken. About all you can do is implement a receive timeout, but that kind of sucks.

Does the protocol have documentation? What does it say to do?

Comment: The protocol defined a message (KeepAlive message). But the message is just sent from the device in some certain cases. In normal, after the client connected to server, the server just waits message from client. I have to determine whether client still connected or not

Comment: @Joker Then it sounds like you should just use a timeout.